# What is the best way to rename (move) file system branches in .NET?

Tags: file, directory, system.io.fileinfo

I would like to rename files and folders recursively by applying a string replacement operation.

E.g. The word "shark" in files and folders should be replaced by the word "orca".

`C:\Program Files\Shark Tools\Wire Shark\Sharky 10\Shark.exe`

should be moved to:

`C:\Program Files\Orca Tools\Wire Orca\Orcay 10\Orca.exe`

The same operation should be of course applied to each child object in each folder level as well.

I was experimenting with some of the members of the `System.IO.FileInfo` and `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` classes but didn't find an easy way to do it.

```
fi.MoveTo(fi.FullName.Replace("shark", "orca"));
```

Doesn't do the trick.

I was hoping there is some kind of "genius" way to perform this kind of operation.
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 1):

So you would use recursion. Here is a powershell example that should be easy to convert to C#:

```
function Move-Stuff($folder)
{
    foreach($sub in [System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories($folder))
      {
        Move-Stuff $sub
    }
    $new = $folder.Replace("Shark", "Orca")
    if(!(Test-Path($new)))
    {
        new-item -path $new -type directory
    }
    foreach($file in [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($folder))
    {
        $new = $file.Replace("Shark", "Orca")
        move-item $file $new
    }
}

Move-Stuff "C:\Temp\Test"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string oldPath = "\\shark.exe"
string newPath = oldPath.Replace("shark", "orca");

System.IO.File.Move(oldPath, newPath);
```

Fill in with your own full paths